# How to measure the length of a Stream in .NET when/after reading it

Tags: c#, .net, stream

In .NET there is naturally no guaranteed way of knowing the length of a `Stream`, since this might be coming from some external source (ex. network), that has not delivered the whole content yet, and may not even have calculated it yet.

Instead what I'm searching for is how to know the length after you've read the whole `Stream`?

I can make the solution myself by making sort of a middle layer wrapper around the `Stream` (like you can do with `CryptoStream` if you want to calculate a hash of the content) but this is rather cumbersome, so I'd like to avoid that (I'm guessing there's an easy way I've overlooked).

Please do not post any solutions that involve having the content of the `Stream` in memory (ex. copying it to a `MemoryStream` or byte array).

Comment: I don't know of anything built-in: you might have to roll your own

Comment: Do you want to support _any_ stream? What if the caller seeks/changes the position? Do you want to return the bytes read/written?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I'm the caller/consumer. And yes in principle I want to support any `Stream` that is readable. I do not wish to change the position, and in the scenarios I will have, this is not a possibility (the `Stream` will not be seekable).

Comment: What code do you write that you need a stream? Do you only call `Read()`? Or do you pass the stream onto other code? But the solution would probably entail to create your own wrapper then. What I mean is: if you call `Read()`, you can simply do `bytesRead += stream.Read()`. Otherwise, you need to wrap a stream and do that on all reading methods, throwing for situations you don't want to support.

Comment: @CodeCaster This can be different scenarios. In one it is a REST endpoint where you can upload files. This REST service saves the stream to a database, but also want's to count the number of bytes it reads.

Another example is a transforming REST service (S1). When you call this service it calls another REST service (S2) that provides the `Stream` to be transformed. The S1 service will then dynamically transform the `Stream` as it streams it to the client calling S1, hence S1 will never have the full `Stream`. But S1 should still be capable of identifying how many bytes it has processed.

Comment: Yes so you do pass the stream to other code, and you assume they linearly consume the entire stream. In that case writing a wrapper should be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

If you own the stream-reading code, the most trivial approach would be to keep count while reading:

```
ulong totalBytes = 0;

do
{
    bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    totalBytes += (ulong)bytesRead;

    // do something with buffer

} while (bytesRead > 0);
```

You can then further use `totalBytes` after fully reading the stream.

This is not feasible if you don't read the stream yourself, but pass it on to other code.

For select streams, you could use the `Postion` property after reading (but before disposing). They'll keep count of where they are. This doesn't work for non-seekable streams nor for streams that are disposed by the reader.

This leaves you to implement an own wrapper that keeps count in `Read` (ultimately called by `BeginRead` and `ReadAsync` as well):

```
public sealed class ByteCountingStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _adaptee;
    private readonly bool _ownsStream;

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Position { 
        get => throw new NotSupportedException();
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public ulong BytesRead { get; private set; }

    public ByteCountingStream(Stream adaptee, bool ownsStream = true)
    {
        if (!adaptee.CanRead)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        _adaptee = adaptee;
        _ownsStream = ownsStream;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int bytesRead = _adaptee.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        BytesRead += (ulong)bytesRead;

        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    {
        int bytesRead = await _adaptee.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);

        BytesRead += (ulong)bytesRead;

        return bytesRead;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_ownsStream)
        {
            _adaptee.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public override void Flush() => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
await using var countingStream = new ByteCountingStream(underlyingStream);

await SomeStreamReadingMethod(countingStream);

var uploadedFileSize = countingStream.BytesRead;
```

Then you can use `uploadedFileSize`. Now if you want to support seeking, you have another problem...

Comment: (It's worth overriding the `ReadAsync` overloads as well)

Comment: @canton why? The base implementation does ... something (calling `Read()` as well), and I wouldn't know how to do that better.

Comment: Currently, if someone calls `ReadAsync` on your wrapper, the base `Stream` implementation has to fall back to calling your `Read` in a background thread, even if the `Stream` you're wrapping supports async reads. This matters if it's something like a network stream: you're taking something which supports async reads and forcing it to do blocking reads in a background thread. Just delegate to `adaptee.ReadAsync`, the same as with `Read`

Comment: @CodeCaster The comments here indicates why I would like to avoid writing my own wrapper althrough I appreciate the efford (and probably will do since nothing else has turned up). There are multiple virtual methods on the `Stream` class for reading and there is a possibility that performance is left on the table unless I override and delegate them all to the underlying `Stream`. Other `async` methods might rely on the legacy asynchronous methods in `Stream` and I wouldn't know without looking at the source code.

Comment: @Ykok I get that, it was more left as an exercise than as a full implementation. I also would not solve this at the stream level like I said. There must be a reason why you're interested in the length. It should be possible to ask this from the sender or receiver without keeping count yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have made my own solution to this problem [here](https://github.com/ykoksen/stream-utilities/blob/main/Lindhart.Utility.IO.Streaming/Streaming/StreamCounter.cs). Basically it is a `Stream` implementation with all the async methods also implemented.